# .NET 4 SDK Does not install Bootstrapper directory

Tags: .net-4.0, msbuild, winapi

I have a problem on our Jenkins CI server.
I've install Windows 7 .NET 4 SDK on it but for some reason it did not install the Bootstrapper directory.
In my local machine I have Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\V7.0a\Bootstrapper but on the server machine it have Windows\V7.1 but it does not have the Bootstrapper directory.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Ido.

Comment: Confirmed.  I guess it is a directory that will only be present when you use the VS installer.  Makes somewhat sense, the directory is used by Setup projects.  Which is a VS feature, not an SDK feature.

Comment: It not exactly true - installing VS on build server is not a reasonable thing to do. If the SDK would include everything the VS SDK include I could simply use it on the build server.

Comment: Not related to development. Try [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: I do think this question deserves to stay here, as developers will much more likely run into this than superusers. Also, when @HansPassant mentions this is a VS feature, not an SDK feature, you might wonder why MS puts it in the "Microsoft SDKs\Windows" folder. Btw, this is not the only case where MS bundles an SDK feature with VS, basically breaking easy CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solve this problem by simply coping the files from my machines to the CI server.
It's not ideal but it works.

Comment: Did you find a better solution by now? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Same problem here. No better solution?